# Use ACL to harmonize permissions inside one folder

Tags: permissions, users, group, acl

Me and a few of my friends can log on my server as, say:

```
user
vser
wser
...
```

They all have their private `/home/user`, but we wish to share another `/home/fiesta` folder, with anyone being able to do anything inside.

I have created a group `fiesta`, added everyone to it then set extended permissions with:

```
setfacl -Rm d:g:fiesta:rw /home/fiesta/
```

But still, if `vser` remotely `rsync`s files into `/home/fiesta/`, then she also sends her permissions along, and so `wser` may not be able to read from it or write inside.

Is there a way to configure ACL so that *any* file or folder entering `/home/fiesta` becomes fully available to everyone, no matter the permissions it has been sent with ?